# Find the volume of the solid that lies under a paraboloid and above xy-plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume

Find the volume of the solid that lies under the paraboloid $z = x^2+ y^2$, above the xy-plane, and outside the cylinder $(x – 1)^2 + y^2= 1$.

I would love to post some work that I've done but I don't even know where to start on this one.

Comment: Outside the cylinder? Is that what you meant, or did you mean inside the cylinder?

Comment: The problem does say outside the cylinder.

Comment: There are no bounds outside the cylinder; there is an infinite amount of volume under the paraboloid but outside the cylinder.